# Problem with Email Sender for verification code .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've read that usually for this type of error you have only to register the new class on your Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender,MyEmailSender>();
```

The problem is that i had it implemented even before the error occurred. Here is the raw error and the code:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'xxxx.Areas.Identity.Services.MyEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'xxxx.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(PageContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(PageContext pageContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Now the code:

> Startup.cs myemail registration

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config => {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                config.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128; })
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
               .AddDefaultUI()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, MyEmailSender>(i =>
                new MyEmailSender(
                    Configuration["EmailSender:Host"],
                    Configuration.GetValue<int>("EmailSender:Port"),
                    Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EmailSender:EnableSSL"),
                    Configuration["EmailSender:UserName"],
                    Configuration["EmailSender:Password"]
                )
            );

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddControllersAsServices();
        }
```

> Register.cshtml.cs

```
namespace xxxx.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly MyEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            MyEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;

        }
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [MinLength(4)]
            [Column(TypeName = "Varchar(30)")]
            public string User { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [MinLength(4)]
            [Column(TypeName = "Varchar(30)")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [MinLength(4)]
            [Column(TypeName = "Varchar(30)")]
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public Gender Gender { get; set; }
            public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
            [DefaultValue(0)]
            public int Coins { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
        }

        public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.User, Email = Input.Email, Name = Input.Name,
                    SurName = Input.Surname, Gender = Input.Gender };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    StringBuilder VerCode = new StringBuilder();
                    Char[] generator = user.Id.ToCharArray();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i = +4)
                    {
                        VerCode.Append(generator[i]);
                    }
                    var verificationCode = VerCode.ToString();
                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        "Your verification code for your registration to Gen/Music is "
                        + verificationCode + " please use this to verify your account!"
                + $"Please write the given code to confirm your account <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>Click here first!</a>.");

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, MyEmailSender>();
> ```

This line adds `IEmailSender` to the DI container, which means that any requests for `IEmailSender` will be satisfied with an instance of `MyEmailSender`. It states something like "whenever `IEmailSender` is required, use an instance of `MyEmailSender`". Note that this does *not* configure the DI container to satsify direct requests for `MyEmailSender`.

> ```
> private readonly MyEmailSender _emailSender;
>
> public RegisterModel(
>     UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
>     SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
>     ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
>     MyEmailSender emailSender)
> {
>     _userManager = userManager;
>     _signInManager = signInManager;
>     _logger = logger;
>     _emailSender = emailSender;
> }
> ```

This is where the problem lies. Switch out your implementation type for the interface, like this:

```
private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

public RegisterModel(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
    ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
    IEmailSender emailSender)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
}
```

This will still use your concrete `MyEmailSender` implementation, as intended.